# Oracle markup into temporary table

Tags: oracle, oracle-text

I'm using ctx_doc.markup to highlight search results and insert them into a temporary table. Then i retrieve the results from the temporary table. All is running in one transaction. However, the results get deleted from the temporary table (or never inserted?) before i can retrieve them. If i use a normal table it's working fine. Here's the query i'm using:

```
BEGIN
  FOR cur_rec IN (SELECT id FROM contents WHERE CONTAINS(text, 'test', 1) > 0)
  LOOP
    CTX_DOC.markup(
      index_name => 'I_CONTENTS_TEXT',
      textkey    => TO_CHAR(cur_rec.id),
      text_query => 'test',
      restab     => 'CONTENTS_MARKUP',
      query_id   => cur_rec.id,
      plaintext  => FALSE,
      tagset     => 'HTML_NAVIGATE');
  END LOOP;
END;
EOF
```

Comment: How is your temporary table defined? ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS? If so, what happens if you change it to ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS - do you see the results as expected?

Comment: It was ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS. i changed it to ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS. Now i see the results as expected. But that doesn't help as i don't want to keep the data till the end of the session.

Comment: If you're not doing an explicit commit/rollback in your code, then I can only assume that `CTX_DOC.markup` (despite there being no mention in the documentation or, as far as I could tell, in Google!) contains a commit/rollback. In that case, you'll have to add in a manual truncate of the GTT once you're done with the results. If you are doing an explicit commit/rollback, then you'll need to remove it if you want to keep the `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS` on the GTT.

Comment: I don't do an explicit commit or rollback. You're probably right assuming that markup does an implicit commit.

Comment: Yeah, I figured you probably weren't from what you said in your question, but just double-checking *{:-)